# Crash on setContentView

Tags: android, android-layout, crashlytics

My application normally working fine without any crashes. In some case(Don't know the scenario) my application crash. The logcat shows the error `Resources$NotFoundException` . This resource is the:

```
setContentView(R.layout.practise_menu);
```

Have any idea about this scenario? When it is possible to crash like this?

My Logcat error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.y/com.x.y}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030032
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030032
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1026)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2131)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:865)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
       at com.x.y.onCreate(Practitioner_menu.java:749)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I got this error report from `crashlytics`. Please help me to find out.

Comment: Are you sure `practise_menu` available in `layout`?

Comment: please paste your full activity code.

Comment: @Amsheer just try to clean and built your project. it's becoz your resources file are not properly built and also check once your project package name should be similar in manifest file.

Comment: This app running perfectly. The layout is available.

Comment: @Amsheer what is the problem? after clean and built your project.

Comment: I don't know when this happened . I can't clean this is running in market

Comment: I got this error from crashylitics. I don't have much details .

Comment: @Amsheer WOW!!!!It's like _MAGIC_!!!!!

Comment: Are you using resource variants like `res/layout-foo` for this layout and a default version is missing in the regular `res/layout` directory in case the more specific variants failed to match the device specs?

Comment: @laalto Sorry i don't get you.

Comment: Where is `practise_menu.xml` in your project?

Comment: it is inside of res/layout-land folder.

Comment: So you're using `layout-land` but there's no version of that layout in `layout`? That would explain why it isn't found in a portrait orientation device.

Comment: But all other Activity works fine. Only this activity have this issue. How to recreate this when it is happened. Please give any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue:

I just created different folders for landscape and portrait
e.g ->

```
layout-land
layout-port
```

But in Androidmanifest file i set the orientation as landscape.

Once i call intent for this activity and press power button and rotate the screen app crash and got this exception.

I don't know what is happening but i guess when the screen rotating it searches the xml file in layout-land and layout-port.

Answer (score 1):

there is issue of the layout resolution,i have faced these kind of issue many times, better create folder structure as given bellow

```
layout-large
layout-small
layout-medium
```